# Issue parsing data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

I and my code seem to be crashing here. I am unable to parse this dataset using jsonDecode, please help. It should be rather simple but it just wont work past the jsonDecode

DataSet

```
[{"data":[{"name":"Alba","visible":true},{"name":"Arad","visible":true}],"_id":"Counties"}]
```

Failing Code

```
Definitions parseDefinition(String responseBody) {
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
return  Definitions.fromJson(parsed);
```

Comment: use this to auto generate your parsing code:
https://app.quicktype.io
. on the left parse your json and on the right choose dart

Comment: Gave a try from the tool, It told me to try this but it didn't work 

```return  json.decode(responseBody).map((x) => Definitions.fromJson(x));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Definitions {
  Definitions({this.data, this.id});
  List<DefData> data;
  String id;
  
  static Definitions fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => Definitions(
    data: List<DefData>
      .from(json['data']
      .map((dynamic d ) => DefData.fromJson(d),)
      .toList(),),
    id: json['_id'],
  );
}

class DefData {
  DefData({this.name,this.visible});
  final String name;
  final bool visible;
  
  static DefData fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => DefData(
    name: json['name'],
    visible: json['visible']
  );
}

void main() {
  
 const String _json = '[{"data":[{"name":"Alba","visible":true},  {"name":"Arad","visible":true}],"_id":"Counties"}]';
  
  List<Definitions> _foos = List.from(jsonDecode(_json))
    .map((dynamic d ) => Definitions.fromJson(d),)
    .toList();
  
  _foos.forEach((Definitions f) {
    f.data.forEach((Baz b) {
      print(b.name);
      print(b.visible);
    });
    print({f.id});
  });
}
```

If you have similar kind of dataset you can use this, it worked for me :)